# Using collection of UDTs vs Denormalized rows in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cql3, cassandra-3.0, datastax-search

Imaging we have 2 tables in RDBMS, INVOICE and INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS and there is a One-To-Many relationship between INVOICE and INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS.

> INVOICE (1) --------> (*) INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS

Above said entity needs to be stored in **Cassandra** now, to do this we can follow 2 approaches,

> 1. Denormalized table with PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id, invoice_line_item_id), for one invoice, there will be multiple line_item_ids.
> 2. A Row for INVOICE with a SET<FROZEN<INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS_UDT>>
> 3. Have 2 tables and take care of updating 2 tables and joining query result in DAO code

**Use Cases are,**

1. User can create an invoice and keep adding, updating and deleting lines
2. User can search with invoice or invoice_line_udt attributes and get invoice details (Using DSE Search solr_query)
3. INVOICE (Header) may contain 20 attributes and each Item (invoice_line) may contain around 30+ attributes a big UDT and each collection may have ~1000 lines.

**Question:**

1. Using a frozen collection affects read and write performance due to serialization and deserialization. Considering UDT contains 30+ fields and a max of 1000 items in collection, is this a good approach or data model?
2. Because there is serialization and deserialization, collection of UDT gets replaced every time record or partition is updated. **Will column updates create tombstones? Considering we have lot of updates in the items (collection of UDTs) will it create a problem?**

**Here is the CQL for approach 1: (Invoice header row having collection of UDTs)**

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS comment_udt (
    created_on timestamp,
  user text,
  comment_type text,
  comment text
);

CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS invoice_line_udt ( ---TO REPRESENT EACH ITEM ---
invoice_line_id text,
invoice_line_number int,
parent_id text,

item_id text,
item_name text,
item_type text,

uplift_start_end_indicator text,
uplift_start_date timestamp,
uplift_end_date timestamp,
bol_number text,
ap_only text,

uom_code text,
gross_net_indicator text,
gross_quantity decimal,
net_quantity decimal,
unit_cost decimal,
extended_cost decimal,

available_quantity decimal,
total_cost_adjustment decimal,
total_quantity_adjustment decimal,
total_variance decimal,

alt_quantity decimal,
alt_quantity_uom_code text,
adj_density decimal,

location_id text,
location_name text,
origin_location_id text,
origin_location_name text,
intermediate_location_id text,
intermediate_location_name text,
dest_location_id text,
dest_location_name text,

aircraft_tail_number text,
flight_number text,
aircraft_type text,

carrier_id text,
carrier_name text,

created_on timestamp,
created_by text,
updated_on timestamp,
updated_by text,
status text,

matched_tier_name text,
matched_on text,
workflow_action text,

adj_reason text,
credit_reason text,
hold_reason text,
delete_reason text,
ap_only_reason text
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoice_by_id ( -- MAIN TABLE --
invoice_id text,
parent_id text,
segment text,
invoice_number text,
invoice_type text,
source text,
ap_only text,
invoice_date timestamp,
received_date timestamp,
due_date timestamp,

vendor_id text,
vendor_name text,
vendor_site_id text,
vendor_site_name text,

currency_code text,
local_currency_code text,
exchange_rate decimal,
exchange_rate_date timestamp,
extended_cost decimal,
early_pay_discount decimal,
payment_method text,
invoice_amount decimal,
total_tolerance decimal,
total_variance decimal,

location_id text,
location_name text,
dest_location_override text,

company_id text,
company_name text,
org_id text,

sold_to_number text,
ship_to_number text,
ref_po_number text,
sanction_indicator text,

created_on timestamp,
created_by text,
updated_on timestamp,
updated_by text,
manually_assigned text,
assigned_user text,
assigned_group text,
workflow_process_id text,
version int,
comments set<frozen<comment_udt>>, 
status text,

lines set<frozen<invoice_line_udt>>,-- COLLECTION OF UDTs --

PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id, invoice_type));
```

**Here is the script for approach 2: (denormalized invoice and lines in one partition but multiple rows)**

```
CREATE TABLE wfs_eam_ap_matching.invoice_and_lines_copy1 ( 
invoice_id uuid, 
invoice_line_id uuid, 
record_type text, 
active boolean, 
adj_density decimal, 
adj_reason text, 
aircraft_tail_number text, 
aircraft_type text, 
alt_quantity decimal, 
alt_quantity_uom_code text, 
ap_only boolean, 
ap_only_reason text, 
assignment_group text, 
available_quantity decimal, 
bol_number text, 
cancel_reason text, 
carrier_id uuid, 
carrier_name text, 
comments LIST<FROZEN<comment_udt>>, 
company_id uuid, 
company_name text, 
created_by text, 
created_on timestamp, 
credit_reason text, 
dest_location_id uuid, 
dest_location_name text, 
dest_location_override boolean, 
dom_intl_indicator text, 
due_date timestamp, 
early_pay_discount decimal, 
exchange_rate decimal, 
exchange_rate_date timestamp, 
extended_cost decimal, 
flight_number text, 
fob_point text, 
gross_net_indicator text, 
gross_quantity decimal, 
hold_reason text, 
intermediate_location_id uuid, 
intermediate_location_name text, 
invoice_currency_code text, 
invoice_date timestamp, 
invoice_line_number int, 
invoice_number text, 
invoice_type text, 
item_id uuid, 
item_name text, 
item_type text, 
local_currency_code text, 
location_id uuid, 
location_name text, 
manually_assigned boolean, 
matched_on timestamp, 
matched_pos text, 
matched_tier_name text, 
net_quantity decimal, 
org_id int, 
origin_location_id uuid, 
origin_location_name text, 
parent_id uuid, 
payment_method text, 
received_date timestamp, 
ref_po_number text, 
sanction_indicator text, 
segment text, 
ship_to_number text, 
sold_to_number text, 
solr_query text, 
source text, 
status text, 
total_tolerance decimal, 
total_variance decimal, 
unique_identifier FROZEN<TUPLE<text, text>>, 
unit_cost decimal, 
uom_code text, 
updated_by text, 
updated_on timestamp, 
uplift_end_date timestamp, 
uplift_start_date timestamp, 
uplift_start_end_indicator text, 
user_assignee text, 
vendor_id uuid, 
vendor_name text, 
vendor_site_id uuid, 
vendor_site_name text, 
version int, 
workflow_process_id text, 
PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id, invoice_line_id, record_type) 
);
```

Note: we use datastax cassandra + DSE Search. It doesn't support static columns, hence we are not using it. Also, in order to give a real picture I have listed tables and UDT with lots of columns and ended up creating a long question.